# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaD:\\NLP\\cv082_11080.csv' in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, filenames

This is my code in pycharm:

```
#coding=utf-8
import csv
path=r'‪D:\NLP\cv082_11080.csv'
with open(path) as f:        # 采用b的方式处理可以省去很多问题
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            print reader
```

But it always gives this error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaD:\NLP\cv082_11080.csv'

But when I run the code in the Python command  line, it works well. So then I lool the setting in pycharm, but the option of file-encoding is right, the project and the IDE coding is both UTF-8.
How do I solve this?

Comment: try `open(path, 'rt')` instead

Comment: thank you! but it's also report  error,i think the error is because of the path .

Comment: use path=r'‪D:\\NLP\\cv082_11080.csv' instead

Comment: On Windows the path may be tricky. Or you could use `os.listdir` to see the proper way to locate the file

Comment: thank you ！I have tried    the three way to  Eliminate the escape character  to solve it ,but come to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error because your path has some invisible characters in it (like the error message suggests):

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\xe2\x80\xaaD:\\NLP\\cv082_11080.csv' in pycharm
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Delete this entire line:

```
path=r'‪D:\NLP\cv082_11080.csv'
```

And type it out by hand again. You probably copy-pasted the path from somewhere and your text editor isn't showing the invisible character.

Those characters are the UTF-8 encoding of `\u202a`, which is a left-to-right mark.

Answer (score -1):

问题出在编码造成的路径错误。
maybe first line code 没有起到作用
建议#coding=utf-8修改为

# coding:utf-8

注意 #  和 coding  之间有一个空格。

Comment: thank you !my  annotation is work well so I think it is right。and I have try you way,also failed!